# Receiving An error occurred while connecting with the scanner. (-9923) when trying to scan from the printer to Mac OS 10.12

Tags: printer, scanner, scanning, hp-envy

Whenever I am trying to scan from the HP Printer Envy 4500 to MacOs Sierra 10.12 it gives me this following error:
[image]

When the printer was installed initially, it used to scan fine but stopped scanning recently. Weirdly though it continues to print fine which indicates there is no specific "communication" issue.

I tried all the 3 methods for scanning indicated [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/quot-Error-occurred-while-communicating-with-the-scanner/td-p/4907625) with no success. Additionally found this forum on [HP Support](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-and-Copying/error-9923-connecting-mac-el-capitan-amp-HP-4630/td-p/5511473) where others have faced a similar issue but no solution has been specified.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the scan driver is corrupted somehow. Try downloading the latest copy of the driver for OSX 10.12 from [HP's site](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-4500-e-all-in-one-printer-series/5304875/model/5304876) and installing that. This is the solution given by [Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7522683?start=0&tstart=0). Other people suggest reinstalling OSX itself, but try the driver first.